# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() в Table Field

Tags: php, drupal

Возникла ошибка в друпал 7, выдал модуль Table Field

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() в функции
>   tablefield_field_formatter_view() (строка 455 в файле
>   X:\home\tt.du\www\sites\all\modules\tablefield\tablefield.module).

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_formatter_view().
 */
function tablefield_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {
  $element = array();
  $settings = $display['settings'];
  $formatter = $display['type'];

  foreach ($items as $delta => $table) {
    // Check for table caption.
    $raw = unserialize($table['value']);
    $caption = isset($raw['caption'])? check_plain($raw['caption']): '';

    // Rationalize the stored data.
    if (!empty($table['tabledata'])) {
      $tabledata = $table['tabledata'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($table['value'])) {
      $tabledata = tablefield_rationalize_table(unserialize($table['value']));
    }

    // Run the table through input filters.
    if (isset($tabledata)) {
      if (!empty($tabledata)) {

        if (!empty($settings['trim_trailing_rows'])) {
          $tabledata = tablefield_rtrim_rows($tabledata);
        }

        if (!empty($settings['trim_trailing_cols'])) {
          $tabledata = tablefield_rtrim_cols($tabledata);
        }

        foreach ($tabledata as $row_key => $row) {
          foreach ($row as $col_key => $cell) {
            if (!empty($table['format'])) {
              $tabledata[$row_key][$col_key] = array(
                'data' => check_markup($cell, $table['format']),
                'class' => array('row_' . $row_key, 'col_' . $col_key),
              );
            }
            else {
              $tabledata[$row_key][$col_key] = array(
                'data' => check_plain($cell),
                'class' => array('row_' . $row_key, 'col_' . $col_key),
              );
            }
          }
        }
      }

      // Check for an empty header, if so we don't want to theme it.
      $noheader = TRUE;
      if (empty($field['settings']['hide_headers'])) {
        $header_data = array_shift($tabledata);
        foreach ($header_data as $cell) {
          if (strlen($cell['data']) > 0) {
            $noheader = FALSE;
            break;
          }
        }
      }

      $header = $noheader ? NULL : $header_data;

      $entity_info = entity_get_info($entity_type);
      $entity_id = !empty($entity_info['entity keys']['id']) ? $entity->{$entity_info['entity keys']['id']} : NULL;

      // Theme the table for display.
      $element[$delta] = array(
        '#theme' => 'tablefield_view',
        '#attributes' => array(
          'id' => 'tablefield-' . $delta,
          'class' => array('tablefield'),
        ),
        '#caption' => $caption,
        '#header' => $header,
        '#rows' => $tabledata,
        '#delta' => $delta,
        '#export' => isset($field['settings']['export']) ? $field['settings']['export'] : NULL,
        '#entity_type' => $entity_type,
        '#entity_id' => $entity_id,
        '#field_name' => $field['field_name'],
        '#langcode' => $langcode,
        '#formatter' => $formatter,
      );
    }

  }
  return $element;
}
```

Ошибка возникает на

```
foreach ($header_data as $cell) {
```

Кто подскажет куда копать

модуль друпала 7 Table Field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замените этот код:

```
if (empty($field['settings']['hide_headers'])) {
  $header_data = array_shift($tabledata);
  foreach ($header_data as $cell) {
    if (strlen($cell['data']) > 0) {
      $noheader = FALSE;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

На такой:

```
if (empty($field['settings']['hide_headers'])) {
  $header_data = array_shift($tabledata);
  if (is_array($header_data)) {
    foreach ($header_data as $cell) {
      if (strlen($cell['data']) > 0) {
        $noheader = FALSE;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Ошибка говорит о том, что в цикл для обработки передано что-то, что невозможно итерировать.

Comment: Спасибо!
Помогло!